# Order a List<T> by Date, but it has a String ID, if that ID is repeated with different date in the collection with should appear below of it

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, linq, linqbridge

I couldn't express better what I am asking in the title.

This is what I'm looking.

I have a disordered List of an Specific Object I have a `DateTime` and `String` Property.

The String Property Has values Like this ones (note that it is an string, not a number, it always has the K letter, I should be ordering with just the numbers):

```
K07000564, 
K07070000
K07069914
K07026318
K07019189
```

What I want is to order the List By Date... but when ordering if the String value is present in the collection with other Date I want to order them just after this one (By Date also in that miniGroup of IdFinders)... and then keep ordering...

Something Like this:

**Edit**

I edited the example to clarify that ordering by IdFinder will not work... I need to order By Date.. if when ordering by Date the IdFinder is present more than once in the collection should show them just after this last one, and then keep ordering the rest of them and so on by each idfinder

```
ID         Date
**K07000564**   Today
K07000562   Yesterday
K07000563   The Day Before Yesterday
**K07000564** The day before the day before yesterday
```

Should be

```
K07000564 Today
K07000564 The day before the day before yesterday
K07000562 Yesterday 
K07000563  The Day Before Yesterday
```

I achieved this in SQL Server 2008 in a project before with something like this:

```sql
WITH B
AS
(
    SELECT 
        ID, 
        MAX(DATE_COLUMN) DATE_COLUMN, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY MAX(DATE_COLUMN) DESC) RN
    FROM MYTABLE
    GROUP BY ID

)

SELECT *
FROM MYTABLE c
, B
WHERE ID= b.ID
ORDER BY b.rn, c.DATE_COLUMN desc;
```

But I'm not good with Linq and I have no idea of how doing this in Linq.

Maybe an Important Note I'm in .NEt 2.0, so no LINQ available but I'm using [Linqbridge](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqbridge.aspx) to use Linq.

I tried this, but as you will notice, this will not work

```
oList.OrderBy(i => i.IdFinder).ThenByDescending(i => i.OperationDate);
```

I hope to have explained this clearly

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: You really have to use .Net 2.0?

Comment: yes I have to, what for? is there a limitation by the LinqBridge? My client have 2.0 not 3.5 or further

Comment: LinqBridge supports only linq to objects.

Comment: that's right, that's what I'm looking for, just order objects, not linq to sql or something

Comment: @Tilak what's wrong with your solution? I think it's what Mr described as expected result

Comment: Make sure your client knows that .NET 3.5 is just .NET 2.0 SP2 plus some new assemblies. It's safe for them to upgrade since, if they don't use the new features, then they have no risk beyond the risks of a service pack.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var result = oList.OrderByDescending(x => x.OperationDate)
                  .GroupBy(x => x.IdFinder)
                  .SelectMany(x => x);
```

Comment: `x.IdFinder` will not be sorted. Though it is not explicitly clear from the question, example shows so.

Comment: I clarified it sorry, idfinder should be sorted by date descending also

Comment: @Mr. This code gives your expected output. The only thing is that I can not test it with `Linqbridge`.

Comment: let me try it out, and I keep u posted

Answer (score 2):

I think this should do the trick:

```
var sortedList = oList
    .GroupBy(x => x.IdFinder)
    .Select(g =>
        new
            {
                MaxOpDate = g.Max(x => x.OperationDate),
                Items = g
            })
    .OrderByDescending(g => g.MaxOpDate)
    .SelectMany(g => g.Items.OrderByDescending(x => x.OperationDate));
```

However, I haven't tested it with Linqbridge.

Comment: I think you also need to order the items in each group.

Comment: it works w0lf it takes a while let me try @I4V answer, + 1, thanks for your help

Comment: @Mr. yes, I hope I4V's solution works because it should be faster, as it only sorts once.

Comment: I think they bot woth work, but they produce different result, maybe because the dates are just dates, without time, and LInq Order them different in both querys,anyway both of them are correct but I4V is faster as you said.  Thank you anyway for your help

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
oList.OrderBy(i => int.parse(i.IdFinder.Substring(1,i.IdFinder.Length-1)).ThenByDescending(i => i.OperationDate);
```

First extract the numeric value out of IdFinder, the orderby this value.

**Note** -> It is assumed that `i.IdFinder` is always a valid "K######" where # is number less than [Int32.MaxValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.maxvalue.aspx).

Comment: This simply orders by id and then by date, but that's not what's being asked for.

Comment: From the example, it looks like order id and date

Comment: From the example yes, but the description says something else.

Comment: +1 Don't know who downvoted this answer, but it's what OP asked for. BTW I can't understand what title says